# How to give script read access to files in a directory on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I created a shell script that deletes duplicates in a given directory. It prints “access denied” followed by file name if a certain file cannot be read. When I try to run `./filename` (name of the shell file) under a certain directory, all the files are printed out with “access denied” next to it.

Permission given:

```
drwxr-xr-x     .
drwx------ 24  ..
-rw-r--r--  1  file1.cpp
-rw-r--r--  1  file2.cpp
-rwxr-xr-x  1  file3.cpp
-rwxr-xr-x  1  file2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1  script
```

Output when I run command `./script` under directory:

```
/file1.cpp: permission denied 
/file2.cpp: permission denied 
/file3.cpp: permission denied 
/file2.txt: permission denied 
/script.sh: permission denied
```

Comment: Exactly what command / line gives the error messages? Does your user have read & write access to the files & directory?

Comment: You do realize that your error message say `/file1.cpp`, in other words a file in the root directory, not in the current directory?

Comment: It is in the current directory. I used the command ls to check it

Comment: command I used is  ./script under a directory.

Comment: i also tried ./script directory1, still not luck

Comment: Please *post the script!* (Comment-within-a-comment: why am I the first person to ask for this?)

Comment: i cant output my script on here, because I need to turn it in thru turnitin.com I can email it to you. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to tell without seeing the code,
but your script is probably doing something like

```
cp "$file" "$dir/$file"
```

where `$file` is set to `file1.cpp` and `$dir` is set to null. 
So it is doing

```
cp file1.cpp /file1.cpp
```

and, of course, you don’t have permission to create `/file1.cpp`
(i.e., to create files in the root directory).

So the solution would be to set `$dir`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give access rights to a script, just to users and groups.

If user running the script doesn't have access to the files, run the script as a user who has access.

In the directory, run these commands and add the output to the question:

```
id
ls -la
```

Then run the script the way you normally execute it and also add the output of that script.

Comment: Oh ok, I ran the script as a user who has access. Still no luck

Comment: Please add the exact error messages and the exact permissions of the files and directories to the question.

Comment: what command should I run in order to execute my script? My script takes a directory as input and modifies that particular directory by removing duplicates. Right now, I'm just executing the command ./file.sh inside the directory. It doesn't work.

Comment: /file1.cpp: permission denied
/file2.cpp: permission denied
/file3.cpp: permission denied
/file2.txt: permission denied
/script.sh: permission denied

Comment: This is the output I get

Comment: Please add the output **to the question** with **proper formatting**.

Comment: Okay I have done that